# Web API async Task await blocking main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

We have a three tier infrastructure (front end which is all Web API 2, Middleware which accepts API calls from front end and runs business logic and databases access, then the DB)

I'm trying to find out why our app locks up when I take the middle tier down.  We use Memcached for all the reads and the front end serves the cached data just fine, but one of the calls that is made checks to see if the user is logged in.  Running on my local machine with one app pool, that call locks the thread (I think) and prevents the rest of the calls from doing anything until the timeout on the autologin call expires.

The code path looks like this:
call to api/autologin --> front end API calls Client.SendAsync (our custom method for passing along data to the middleware), this tries to call the middlewware by using HttpClient.SendAsAsync with a timeout of 3 minutes (Probably should shorten this)
My expectation is that this should release this thread while we are waiting.  That does not appear to be the result.
The REALLY weird thing is that when the middleware is down the Client.SendAsync gets ran MANY time, like 10.  I thought this was maybe HTTP 2.0 in Chrome, but I switched to Fiddler and it did the same thing.  Very weird.

So, two questions.
1.  What's with the multiple calls?
2.  Why do the threads appear to be getting locked?

Here's the code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Auto login user if they have the persistent cookies.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The groups the logged in user has access to in the form of a 
LoggedInUserData object.</returns>
[Route("api/cms/autologin/")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AutoLogin()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(this.Request);
    return this.LoginCacheHelper(response);
}
```

That calls

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return await Client.SendAsync<string>(request, null, null, false);
}
```

Which calls

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, T content = null, string route = null, bool isFile = false, TimeSpan? timeout = null) where T : class
{
    // Validate all internal certs.
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    // Determine the route and make sure route has a starting forward slash.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(route) && route.StartsWith("http"))
    {
        // Check to make sure this is a selinc.com domain for security purposes.
        if (Sel.Utils.Validation.UriValidation.IsSelincDomain(route))
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(route);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string middlewareRoute = GetRoute(route, request);

        // Change Uri to middle ware.
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(Config.MwareSiteUrl + middlewareRoute);
    }

    // Remove host header
    request.Headers.Host = string.Empty;

    // Set content of request.
    // File content will be kept on the request as is.
    if (content != null && !isFile)
    {
        request.Content = new ObjectContent<T>(content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
    else if (!isFile)
    {
        request.Content = null;
    }

    // Client handler set use cookies to false which will pass along the current cookies
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false };

    // The HttpClient object
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.Timeout = timeout ?? new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);

    // Send the request
    return await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Adding image of the Network log in Chrome to illustrate the behavior.
[image]
Note that if I remove the API call to the autologin, everything works fine.  It's the only call in this stack that hits the back end.

Also note: If I modify the SendAsync method to just return a new HttpResponseMessage (and thus do no work) then the autologin basically does nothing, returns quickly and site loads as it should, with the middleware server down.  This is just to prove that it is the autologin API call causing the problem.  The autologin API call is the only method calling SendAsync at this time so it's a valid test.

```
// Send the request
////return await client.SendAsync(request);
return new HttpResponseMessage();
```

Comment: 1) How are you checking that threads are getting locked? 2) What line does it "lock up" on if you stop execution from inside the debugger.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain For #1, I'm actually not sure.  When I load the page everything loads fine until we get to that call in the network tab, then it sits there waiting and all the calls after it as well.  For #2, The application is not locking up, it's not a thread issue.  That call waits for the 3 minute timeout to finish then it completes, then the rest of the site loads.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain   It is the  return await client.SendAsync(request); line that is waiting, which it should since the middleware is down and thus not responding.  It's the fact the res of the calls are being blocked when this is an async task I don't understand.

Comment: Thats the point of async/await. It makes async code act like syncronous blocking code, preventing the code after it executing until the async part completes. The data is not supposed to load till your await is done. If you want to do other stuff while you are waiting to the function to finish you need to not call `await` right away while you are doing your other work that does not depend on the result. What do you expect `this.LoginCacheHelper(response);` to do if you have not gotten a result from `await client.SendAsync(request)` yet?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  Right, I get that.  I want it to "stop and wait", but I don't want it to hold the thread.  The rest of the API calls being executed after the autologin should be continuing.  They where called by the browsers and are completely separate.  I'll upload another screenshot to illustrate.

Comment: So basically you're saying that: client browser does not receive responses from other requests while AutoLogin is being processed - is it correct? In this case I would try to understand if it is *client* issue or *server* issue, for example running AutoLogin in one client, and another request in another client - will another client succeed? If yes (and I suspect it should) - you don't have any server-side issues.